# The list item could not be inserted or updated because of invalid values

Tags: sharepoint-online, survey

I have a survey. Some people can respond without any problem, some receive this error:

> The list item could not be inserted or updated because of invalid values.

All users have the same permissions. Two similar surveys work without any problems.

Comment: What are the datatypes of your question? Does it have any complex types like Lookup, External data...

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Login SharePoint site by problematic users, access the NewForm and EditForm by the URLs below, edit the page and edit the web part.

Check if the “Standard(StandardLayout)” is selected in the CSR Render Mode.

https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/Lists/survey1/NewForm.aspx

https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/Lists/survey1/EditForm.aspx

[image]

2. Clear IE cache.
3. Create a new survey list and check if the same issue will occur for the problematic users.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me.

I discovered that the list I was referencing was not the list I thought.  The users that did not get the error just happen to choose items where the ID was in both the correct and incorrect list.